# jQuery Autocomplete (Simple App)

Tags: php, jquery, oracle-call-interface

**index1.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="presidents.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#presidentsServerInput").autocomplete({
                source: 'getname1.php',
                minLength: 2
            })
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<label for="presidentsServerInput">Select President (server-side): </label>
<input id="presidentsServerInput"/>
</body>
</html>
```

**getname1.php**

```
<?php
$searchTerm = $_GET['term'];
$results=array();
$conn = oci_connect("xxxxx", "yyyyy", "zzzzzzz");
$query = "SELECT first_name FROM employees where first_name like '" . $searchTerm . "%'";
$stid = oci_parse($conn, $query);
$r = oci_execute($stid);        
echo oci_num_rows ($stid);
while ($row = oci_fetch_object($stid)) {
    array_push($results,$row->FIRST_NAME);  
}
echo json_encode($results);
?>
```

I can see in FirePHP that it is printing the array correctly but I'm not getting the suggestions on my text box.

Can someone tell me where I'm making mistake?

Comment: Are there any JavaScript errors? Are you sure you're accessing the PHP page correctly?

Comment: I dont see any java script error. On fireBug i see following "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/app/images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_100_eeeeee_1x100.png" and i printed the query in my PHP - SELECT first_name FROM employees where first_name like 'St%' and resultant array ["Steven","Steven","Stephen"]

Comment: Not sure if you've already seen this but jQuery UI has [an example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote) with source.

Comment: I think i am following same, still cannot see the autosuggest populated in my textbox. My PHP code i modified a bit as  while ($row = oci_fetch_object($stid)) {
     $results [] = $row;

  }
 print($searchTerm . "\n");
 echo json_encode($results);

Answer (score 0):

Look into the open select and close methods for jQuery UI Auto-complete from the example on jQuery http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp

Comment: I am working on my local machine. I checked this example and its contacting external entity and reading the response accordingly